# Подскажите где моя ошибка? Проблема с json

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код:

```
import json

filename = 'f_num.json'

def get_new():
    
    try:
        with open(filename) as f:
            fav_n = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
    else:
        return fav_n


def f_num():
    fav_n = input("Введите ваше любимое число: ")
    filename = 'f_num.json'
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(fav_n, f)
        return fav_n

 
def ur_n():
    fav_n = get_new()
    if fav_n:
        print(f"Я знаю ваше любимое число! Это {fav_n}")
    else:
        fav_n = f_num()
        print(f"Мы запомнили ваше любимое число! {fav_n} ")


ur_n()
```

Подскажите где моя ошибка

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: ошибка ваша состоит в том, что вы не написали, что именно ваш код делает «не так».

Comment: виноват, исправил

Comment: Не исправил. [ask]

Comment: Странная ошибка при данном коде вряд ли такая будет. Приведите **полный стек-трейс ошибки**, прямо вот со всеми строками, и прямо в вопрос его. Да, он длинный, но это и хорошо.

Comment: Вангую, что вы пытаетесь пустой файл декодировать как json. Пустая строка не является корректным json, отсюда ошибка.

Comment: @insolor Но в ошибке вообще `None`. Сдаётся мне, что нам показали ошибку от другой версии кода.

Comment: @CrazyElf код обрабатывает ошибку отсутствующего файла, но не учитывает что файл может быть пустым.

Comment: @insolor А, ну может и правда этот `None` не при делах, лень проверять. Скорее всего правда пустой файл.